# Web based large files upload with resume facility in django or asp.net

Tags: asp.net, python, django, file-upload, uploading

We are looking for an approach for developing a web based application which should have facility to upload large files (size upto 10 GB) with resume facility.

We want to develop this application using python/django or C#/asp.net.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the standard upload functionality of the browser for such large files is rather insane. For such files you rather expose ftp functionality to a disk where you can have, in .NET, have a windows service monitor a certain folder and if something gets dropped there act accordingly. .NET has a [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) available to aid you in your effort.

Answer (score 1):

[plupload](http://plupload.org) with the Java backend will support files up to any size.

https://github.com/jakobadam/plupload-java-runtime

You will need to port the uploading portion to Django. It would be something like this.  Although this does not do any checksum verification.

```
def fileUpload(request):
    """file upload for plupload"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.REQUEST.get('name','')
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
        if not name:
            name = uploaded_file.name
        name,ext = os.path.splitext(name)

        #check to see if a user has uploaded a file before, and if they have
        #not, make them a upload directory

        upload_dir = "/results/referenceLibrary/temp/"

        if not os.path.exists(upload_dir):
            return render_to_json({"error":"upload path does not exist"})

        dest_path = '%s%s%s%s' % (upload_dir,os.sep,name,ext)

        chunk = request.REQUEST.get('chunk','0')
        chunks = request.REQUEST.get('chunks','0')
        md5chunk = request.REQUEST.get('md5chunk', False)
        md5total = request.REQUEST.get('md5total', False)

        debug = [chunk, chunks, md5chunk, md5total]

        with open(dest_path,('wb' if chunk==0 else 'ab')) as f:
            for content in uploaded_file.chunks():
                f.write(content)

        if int(chunk) + 1 >= int(chunks):
            #the upload has finished
            pass

        return render_to_json({"chuck posted":debug})

    else:
        return render_to_json({"method":"only post here"})
```